# Align logging messages of different levels

Tags: python, logging, module

I'm using Python's [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module like this:

```
class InitLogging():
    def LogModule(self):
        self.Logger          = logging.getLogger("_TCP_Logger")
        self.Logger.LogLevel = logging.DEBUG
        self.Logger.setLevel(self.Logger.LogLevel)
        self.fh              = logging.FileHandler("Log.txt")
        self.fh.level        = logging.DEBUG
        self.formatter       = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)8s')
        self.Logger.addHandler(self.fh)        
        self.Logger.log(logging.INFO,"=====================================")
        self.Logger.log(logging.INFO,"Start Logging Module!!")
        self.Logger.log(logging.INFO,"=====================================")
        self.fh .setFormatter(self.formatter)
        self.Logger.log(logging.INFO,"Enrty to Logging Module!!")

class LogMsg(InitLogging):
    def Logit(self):
        self.LogModule()
        self.Logger.log(logging.DEBUG,'This is Debugging Message!!')
        self.Logger.log(logging.INFO,"This is Info Message!!")
        self.Logger.log(logging.WARNING,"This is WARNING Message!!")

LoggingInstance = LogMsg()
LoggingInstance.Logit()
```

When I run my code I get the output below in `Log.txt`:

```
=====================================
Start Logging Module!!
=====================================

2013-03-20 17:51:35,135 INFO Enrty to Logging Module!!
2013-03-20 17:51:35,135 DEBUG This is Debugging Message!!
2013-03-20 17:51:35,135 INFO This is Info Message!
2013-03-20 17:51:35,135 WARNING This is WARNING Message!!
```

But I'd like to align messages of different log levels together, producing output like below:

```
=====================================
Start Logging Module!!
=====================================
2013-03-20 17:51:35,135 INFO       Enrty to Logging Module!!
2013-03-20 17:51:35,135 DEBUG      This is Debugging Message!!
2013-03-20 17:51:35,135 INFO       This is Info Message!
2013-03-20 17:51:35,135 WARNING    This is WARNING Message!!
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Looks like there's a sensible question here, but it needs a better title or nobody who could benefit from it will ever find it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a width to the `levelname` field in the formatter's format string.

This is left-aligned:

```
self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-10s %(message)s')

                         levelname
                       |----------|
2013-03-20 16:46:50,573 INFO       Enrty to Logging Module!!
2013-03-20 16:46:50,573 DEBUG      This is Debugging Message!!
2013-03-20 16:46:50,573 INFO       This is Info Message!!
2013-03-20 16:46:50,573 WARNING    This is WARNING Message!!
```

This is right-aligned:

```
self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)10s %(message)s')

                         levelname
                       |----------|
2013-03-20 16:51:04,648       INFO Enrty to Logging Module!!
2013-03-20 16:51:04,650      DEBUG This is Debugging Message!!
2013-03-20 16:51:04,650       INFO This is Info Message!!
2013-03-20 16:51:04,650    WARNING This is WARNING Message!!
                       |0123456789|
                       | width=10 |
```

[String formatting documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)